# If A, B, and C are Boolean variables, which of the following statements are true?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

I. $A\wedge (B\vee C) = (A\wedge B) \vee (A\wedge C)$

II. $A\vee (B\wedge C) = (A\vee B) \wedge(A\vee C)$

III. ($A\wedge B) \vee C = C \vee (B \wedge A)$

How can I do solve this? I'm not entirely sure how to go about this since I am fairly new to Discrete Math. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make truth tables for each of them.

In the first one, note that on the LHS, $A$ must always be true, and at least one of $B$ or $C$ must be true. This is obviously the same as the RHS, hence equality holds.

In the equation, note that at least one of $A$ or ($B$ and $C$) must be true. This also works for the right-hand side.

In the last one, note that at least one of ($A$ and $B$) or $C$ must be true. Note that if we set $A$ to true, $B$ to false, and $C$ to false, then the left-hand side is false. However, the right-hand side is true. Thus, this does not hold.

So the first two are true. The third is not.

Comment: I just corrected the sign in the third one. So would it still be false?

Comment: It's still false. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with the distributive and associative properties of the operators $\lor$ (disjunction) and $\land$ (conjunction).

For the first one:

$$A\land(B\lor C)=(A\land B) \lor (A\land C), \text{ by the distributivity of $\land$ with $\lor$}.$$

If you want (or need) to prove this distributivity yourself, you can use something called a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). For all your varibales, here $A,B,C$ you put in all combinations of true and false for your variables, and check if the truth values for all of the rows match for your two expressions:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A& B & C & A\land(B\lor C) & (A\land B) \lor (A \land C) \\ \hline
T& T & T & T & T\\ \hline
T &T  &F & T & T\\ \hline
T &F  &T & T & T\\ \hline
T &F  &F & F & F\\ \hline
F &T  &T & F & F\\ \hline
F &T  &F & F & F\\ \hline
F &F  &T & F & F\\ \hline
F &F  &F & F & F\\ \hline
\end{array}
Since all truth values in the fourth and fifth column for the expressions we want to check match, these two expressions are equivalent and the statement is true.

**Try it yourself for the second and third statement by writing out the truth table.**

If the expressions get crazy long, you can also create columns with intermediate results.